# Ruby: totalling amounts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Donation.rb model with an `amount` column that takes an integer. I want to sum all the individual donations together and show the total on the home page.

In the home_controller, I'm doing   `@donations = Donation.all` and then in the view I do

```
<% sum = 0 %>
<% @donations.each do |donation| %> 
<%= sum += donation.amount if donation.amount? %>
<% end %>
```

The problem is that this is printing the running sum each time a new donation is added to it. I just want the total sum at the end after they've all been added together.

Comment: I'm no Rails expert, but I'd say you'd probably want to be doing the sum addition in the controller or something and then just displaying the sum in the view using `<%= sum %>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting running sum printed, because you're actually printing it with the `=` sign.
You need to change this line:

```
<%= sum += donation.amount if donation.amount? %>
```

With:

```
<% sum += donation.amount if donation.amount? %>
```

And then, just print the value of `sum` wherever you want doing:

```
<%= sum %>
```

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't be doing any calculations in the view, this stuff should be done in the controller or model if it can be. For something like this I'd do in the controller

```
@donations = Donation.paginate(:page => params[:page], :order => 'created_at desc', :per_page => 20)
@sum = Donation.sum(&:amount)
```

Then simply print out the @sum in the view

```
<%= @sum %>
```

Comment: As a note, do keep in mind that `Donation.all` could be a very large list of items. It's almost always a good idea to paginate these things so you never load every single record in the database.

Answer (score 1):

This should print the sum once its done calculating.

```
<% sum = 0 %>
<% @donations.each do |donation| %> 
  <% sum += donation.amount if donation.amount? %>
<% end %>
<%= sum %>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because any instance of `<%= ... %>` will inline the result. The regular `<% ... %>` version will not.

Don't do this kind of computation in the view, though. Make a class method on Donation which will handle it for you. If you need more than one line to express a computation in a view, make a helper method, or better, a model method.